# Use MBR instead of GPT for system partition

Tags: mbr, gpt

I am really tired of fact that no linux boot cd can be used with Windows 10 GPT partitions, i am considering to simply use MBR instead for my OS partition and others, is this good idea, performance wise its same?

Comment: what do you mean by MFT? It's the Master File Record in NTFS which has nothing to do with partition layouts. And `no linux boot cd can be used with Windows 10 GPT partitions` is absolutely wrong. Use rufus to created Linux boot CDs if you don't have deep GPT knowledge, don't use the `dd` method

Comment: probably you mean MBR instead of MFT

Comment: Yes i meant MBR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you are suggesting with Windows 10, but I do not recommend such. Windows 10 is nearing end of life. Some Linux will work with GPT so look for that.

You cannot use legacy boot with Windows 11.  Even dual boot can be tricky with Windows 11.

Numerous people in here forged ahead with dual boot and are busy now rebuilding their systems.

You are best to use Virtual Machines for an alternate OS. This works great and I use this approach.

Please read this thread:

[Restore Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/1789566/booting-windows-from-gnu-grub-2-06)