# Booting Windows from GNU Grub 2.06

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot, partitioning, grub

***UPDATE***

I have managed to get into the startup menu with the F1, F2, F9, F10, F11 menu.

I am confused as when I hit F10 for the BIOS setup and then I go to boot options and select the USB and save and exit?

I am unsure what steps need to be taken from BIOS to boot the USB and get Windows back on to the computer as primary OS.

So, here goes. . .

I have an HP Pavilion Laptop capable of doing DUAL Boot. I installed Ubuntu on it and I selected do not delete Windows partition. Well it did.

I am trying to get rid of Ubuntu (not a fan) and reinstall Windows.

I have tried:

1. Creating a bootable USB with Windows 11 ISO
2. set root=(hd0) and set root=(hd1) (only options that popped up when hitting tab)
   insmod part_gpt
   insmod ntfs
   insmod chain
   chainloader /Win11_22H2_English_x64v2.iso (the file on the USB)
   - I was unsure honestly if this would work and it didn't :(
3. and a few others to say the least - I won't bore you with the long a** list!!

I need to put Windows back on the computer that currently only has Ubuntu.

Please HELP!!!!!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the USB is bootable, start, boot with the Windows 11 ISO, let it format, create its 3 partitions and install Windows. This will work - I have done it.  You can use Rufus to make the USB bootable.

Ask HP Support for the Recovery USB.  That is another, and decent way, to install Windows.

When done, use Virtual Machines to experiment with alternate systems, not dual boot.

Comment: what do you mean make sure it is bootable? I followed the steps that it said to create a bootable USB.

also, the laptop only has one partition as of right now and that is the one containing Ubuntu. 

while trying to load it did give me an error of no more space or something

Comment: You can use Rufus to make the ISO bootable. Amended answer

Comment: got ya. . . I just used the media creation tool by Windows

Comment: It will automatically boot from the USB right? 

or do I need to prompt it from command line in GNU Grub to make it work?

Comment: @RichardHaverty, use the BIOS menu to boot from the bootable USB drive you just created.

Comment: I'm unable to access BIOS menu since only Ubuntu is running on the laptop

Comment: sorry for the delayed responses, still trying to google and research to figure it out and I get lost down the rabbit hole lol

Comment: You should not have start in BIOS to install Windows. I have not had to at any rate

Comment: I got in touch with HP support finally and was told to use the HP Cloud Recovery Tool. . .  . .As you can imagine no help . . . I did the thing it formatted and all that ejected it booted it from BIOS F9 like I was told and it shows HP on the device now but it doesn't actually finish the installation process or whatever it's supposed to do. HP says that you can't use it from Windows/Microsoft it has to be from HP and that is why it was failing

Comment: So have you now got just Windows installed?

Comment: No I didn't get it. the HP Cloud Recovery tool didn't work and HP is useless as I am not spending more money for support. IDK what to do with this tish now lol

Comment: I don't know for sure. I have always been able to install Windows. Get FDISK on a bootable USB (Rufus) and use that to delete ALL partitions. Then try again.

Comment: so I have no partitions or drivers apparently cause when I do get Windows to start to load it prompts me to select a driver and there are none to choose from :(

Comment: Unless you view the computer as a write-off, you should engage HP to get Windows Installed. That will be a good learning in NOT using Dual Boot

Comment: yeah  I never will do that again and also I am not paying for HP Smart Friend or whatever so I actually have a call with Microsoft support scheduled for the morning